# Why does my Glass Object look low poly despite subsurf modifier and shade smooth?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, glass, shader-nodes

I imported an SVG, extruded it and made a 3d object out of it. I applied shade smooth and a subdivision surface modifier. Still the shape appears very low poly and you can see corners and edges in the reflections. how can I make the glass smoother?

[Blend File](https://we.tl/t-mBW4j8ARsZ)

[image: Render]

[image: Shader Editor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the Subsurface Modifier set to Simple, which doesn't smooth the geometry, only adds it by subdividing each face. Given that the mesh had enough geometry already to look smooth, I removed all subsurface modifiers and check Auto Smooth under Object Data > Normals > Auto Smooth. The Auto Smooth option keeps sharp edges looking sharp even when smooth is enabled.

[image]

[image]